# Is there a way to prevent javascript within a shadow dom from accessing the DOM outside of it?

Tags: javascript, dom, shadow-dom

So if I have:

[image]

The js can change the text in `component_test_div`

Can I prevent that?

Comment: Even if it *were* possible (I don't think it is), since you're using jQuery - which is being loaded outside of the shadow DOM - there's no way for jQuery to 'know' that it is within the shadow DOM. So TLDR no

Comment: i have no idea why this question got down voted. I believe THAT is exactly one of the features which will be REQUIRED by future decentralized operating systems. We're implementing one. and THAT would be of a tremendous importance to provide boundaries between graphical applications running within the same tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Script is not protected by shadow DOM

Shadow DOM only protects CSS leakage or interference with the content of the shadowRoot. It does not create a new namespace for JavaScript.

The code within shadow DOM is just code and has access to everything that is available to code that lives in a regular script file.

In this example I have some JS in the shadow root:

```js
class MyEl extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
    let s = document.createElement('script');
    s.textContent = "function dog() { console.log('Bark, Bark'); }";
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(s);
  }
}

customElements.define('my-el', MyEl);

setTimeout(()=>dog(), 2000);
```

```html
<my-el></my-el>
```

After 2 seconds we call the function `dog()` and it works. That is because, even though this code is placed into a  tag inside a shadowRoot, it still executes in the global scope.

The code OF a component is kept within the component's class and is bound by the rules of code in a class. Private members are not accessible from the outside.

Given that there is no way to segregate your JavaScript in a web component you need to remember that it is available to anyone within its scope.

If you place the code in an IIFE then you can prevent the outside from calling in. But there is still no way to keep the inside from calling out or manipulating things outside of the scope.

---

#### Alternate way to determine if your element is in shadowDOM

As an alternate to @Angel Politis's answer there is an easier way to determine if an element is in someone's shadowRoot:

```js
function isInShadowDOM(el) {
  let ret = false;

  if (el.getRootNode) {
    doc = el.getRootNode();
    ret = (doc !== document);
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **closed Shadow DOM** to the element you want to protect.

```js
component_test_div.attachShadow( { mode: "closed" } )
                  .innerHTML = "READ-ONLY"
                  
app_list.attachShadow( { mode: "closed" } )
        .appendChild( script.content )
```

```html
<div id="component_test_div"></div>

<div id="app_list"></div>

<template id="script">
    <script>
        console.info( "shadowRoot is", component_test_div.shadowRoot )
        component_test_div.textContent = "SHADOWED BY SHADOW DOM"
    </script>
</template>
```

The content of the shadow root will replace any initial or altered text.
The **closed** property will prevent other scripts from accessing the shadow root.

[image]

Comment: He isn't asking about outside script getting into the shadow DOM. He is asking about scripts that are placed IN the shadow DOM and preventing them from getting at things outside of the shadow. And that is not possible.

Comment: @Intervalia in this case it's a duplicate

Comment: Do you have the duplicate number?

Comment: at least https://stackoverflow.com/q/45291529/4600982 but I think I read another similar question that got an answer

Comment: Yes these are duplicates